# Strip any character that is above 127 in the ASCII table?

Tags: jquery, unicode, strip

I am trying to remove strange characters. Those strange characters are apparently very difficult to remove. In this jsfiddlee I included a lot of examples from stackoverflow answers like this, but I cannot get it to work.

```
$("textarea").text().replace(/[^A-Za-z 0-9 \.,\?""!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-_=\+;:<>\/\\\|\}\{\[\]`~]*/g, '');
$("textarea").text().replace(/[\uE000-\uF8FF]/g, '');
$("textarea").text().replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
$("textarea").text().replace(/./g,function(char){
    return char.charCodeAt(0)<=255 ? char : '<b>' + char + '</b>';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vc39F/1/

I just realised I forgot to add the replaced text into the text(), so the textarea does not get replaced.

The textarea contains weird characters, and those are the ones I want to strip. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is NO character with code higher than 255 in **ASCII** table.

Comment: FYI: 127 (delete) is the highest numbered ASCII character. Others are from different ASCII-based extended character sets, like Latin-1, CP-437, UTF-8 and so on.

Comment: Ah damn I also noticed my replace is all wrong. I forgot to put the replace INSIDE the text(). So it actually does replace it, but it doesn't set the new textarea to be the replaced text. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the third option in the list:

```
$("textarea").text(function(_, value) {
    return value.replace(/[^\x00-\xFF]/g, '');
});
```

Seems to work as intended, but is rather open to control characters in the ASCII range. The best is to strip out letters that aren't in the printable range.

```
$('textarea').text(function(_, value) {
    return value.replace(/[^ -~]/g, '');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vc39F/2/)

Comment: This is a perfect solution `value.replace(/[^ -~]/g, '')`, thanks!